# Bash double condition: "Yy" or free string but not "Nn"

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying for my update script to find a way to get a double if with conditions: I can type "Yy" to download the latest version, or type anything else (another version number) but which is not "Nn" (basically cancelling the task).

Tried that, it's working for the "Yy" and the free text but I still can type "Nn" and it downloads me the n.zip file (it should stop the task)

```
if [[ "$latest_confirm" =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] || [[ ! "$latest_confirm" =~ ^[Nn]$ ]]; then
```

Comment: Do you really have a three-way distinction, or do you only care about `Nn` vs anything-but-Nn?

Comment: Can be "Yy", 46.4 or 4.7.0-rc1 but not "Nn"

Comment: But do you "y" and a version number do different things? (Or is "y" basically a synonym for the latest version number?)

Comment: Nah just Y, N or a version :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
latest_version=4.9
read latest_confirm
if [[ $latest_confirm =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
    version=$latest_version
elif [[ $latest_confim =~ ^[Nn]$ ]]; then
    ...
else
    version=$latest_confirm
fi

...
```

Instead of the `else`, you might want another reg-ex comparison to make sure the value is a valid version number.

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked this way if anyone wanting to know about the solution to update my installed softwares:

```
upgrade_pma() {
    old="pma-old"
    new="pma-new"

    header "PHPMYADMIN UPGRADE"
    latest_version=$(check_version pma)
    ask_latest "PHPMyAdmin" $pma_version $latest_version true

    # Detect version to install
    if [[ "$install_version" =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
        install_version_nb=$latest_version
        version_url="https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/$latest_version/phpMyAdmin-$latest_version-all-languages.zip"
    else
        install_version_nb=$install_version
        version_url="https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/$install_version/phpMyAdmin-$install_version-all-languages.zip"
    fi

    # Download file and process install
    if [[ ! "$install_version" =~ ^[Nn]$ ]]; then
        cd $tools/phpmyadmin
        if wget -O pma.zip "$version_url"; then
            unzip pma.zip && rm $_
            mkdir $new && mv phpMyAdmin-$install_version_nb-all-languages/* $new
            cp -R www/config.inc.php $new/
            mv www $old && mv $new www
            chowwwn . && cmf644 . && cmd755 .

            # Check if everything works, then delete the old version
            section "PHPMyAdmin upgraded successfully"
            ask_deleteold
            if [[ "$deleteold" =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
                rm -rf $old phpMyAdmin-$install_version-all-languages/
            fi
        fi
    fi
    exit 0
}
```